# What does passing `this` to a function inside ng-click expose?

Tags: angularjs

Assume we have a button with a ng-click directive.It calls a function passing `this` as an argument.
Upon inspection, the type of the parameter passed is found to be an object.But neither does it have any of the element properties , nor is it a jQuery selector.

What exactly gets passed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngClick` and similar directives are executed in context of the *current* scope. So `this` refers scope object.

If you don't have `ngRepeat`, `ngInclude` or other directive that creates new scope then you can check in controller function and verify that this `ng-click="test(this)"` will pass `something` as `$scope`:

```
$scope.test = function(something) {
    console.log(something === $scope); // => true
}
```

Another example. With ngRepeat you get new child scope per iteration, so in this case if you have this list:

```
<li ng-repeat="n in numbers">
    <button ng-click="test(this)">{{n}}</button>
</li>
```

you will have `something` being a child of the main `$scope`:

```
$scope.test = function(something) {
    console.log(something.$parent === $scope); // => true
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/nxxCn7SYUA4PfJpJoueu?p=info